# How do I pass an array of images to a variable of type UIImageView in swift? Or what is the right way to store multiple images in a single array?

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

/* Created IBOutlets for the dices on the Interface builder. */
@IBOutlet weak var diceImageView1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var diceImageView2: UIImageView!
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func rollDiceButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    diceImageView1.image = [UIImage(named: "DiceOne"), UIImage(named: "DiceTwo")]
 }
}
```

I want to pass a series of images to my diceImageView1 variable which is of type UIImageView but my code is not working. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `UIImageView.image` [is a single `UIImage?`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/1621069-image), not an array of images. If you're trying to display multiple images at once, you'll need multiple image views. If you're trying to cycle through multiple images, you'll have to use a timer and update the image view's image to whatever you want to display at the time you want to display it.

Comment: Alright thank you. But how do I create an array of images in Swift? I understand how to work with arrays of strings and number in swift but I need to create an array or images, maybe 4 or 5 images.

Comment: You already created an array of images in the `@IBAction`. But rather than assigning it (falsely) to an image view assign it to a variable.

Comment: Thank you @vadian, I tried what u suggested, it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func rollDiceButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    diceImageView1.image = [UIImage(named: "DiceOne"), UIImage(named:   "DiceTwo")][1] // where 1 refers to the index, could be any number from 0
 }
```

I added an array index to the end of the array values and it worked fine.